# Best way to modify a custom configuration file via web interface?

Tags: php, javascript, python, configuration

So in our project we have a config file that looks something like

```
%class
name: class1 
option1: on
optionN: off
%classend
```

I need to make a web interface for easy modification of this file. I was thinking of using JavaScript with either PHP or Python (doesn't really make a lot of difference).

So how would I go about implementing this? Should I store values of the options in arrays or variables? But then, how would I create a separate array or variables for each class? What if there is 1000 classes?

Or maybe I shouldn't store anything anywhere at all and just locate the needed option with regex in real time?

And could I have some code examples on how it is best to associate settings with a class? So that for example the program 'knows' that option1: on belongs to the class with name class1.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, I would suggest some sort of a structured format such as [XML](http://www.w3.org/XML/) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/) instead of inventing your own.

The benefits of doing this are:

- People have written encoders and parsers for those structured formats, so you can easily grab a library and use it with the language of your choice.
- Structured formats can be easily portable across different applications.
- Any third party can easily implement your configuration file into their application.

As for editing them using a web interface, if you are using XML or YAML, PHP's excellent XML and YAML extensions should allow you to easily walk through the config file and modify the variables you require.

As for associating settings with a class, this can be easily solved by using XML or YAML.

In XML, your file could look like this

```
<class name="class1">
 <option1>on</option1>
 <optionN>off</optionN>
</class>

<class name="class2">
 <option1>on</option1>
 <optionN>off</optionN>
</class>

<class name="class3">
 <option1>on</option1>
 <optionN>off</optionN>
</class>
```

Comment: I actually think that this is the best way to go too. But in our project there is already a custom config file that is used in some other places as well. That's why I'm having some troubles with it. Would be much easier with XML or for example INI.

Comment: @radioprotector: in that case, perhaps you could write a pair of custom-config-to-XML and XML-to-custom-config converters. That would enable you to do the manipulation work via XML, and then save back in the custom-config format.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create 2 php pages to manage this config file:
1. read.php: Read the config file and display it in a friendly way
2. save.php: Save what you modify

The example code of read.php:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('config.cfg', 'r');
# Read the file line by line
$curr = '';
while(!feof($f)){
    $line = fgets($f);
    if ($line=='%class'){
        $line = fgets($f);
        $classname = explode(': ', $line)[1];
        $curr = $classname;
        $cfg[$classname] = array();
    }
    if ($line=='%classend'){
        continue;
    }
    $opt = explode(': ', $line);
    $cfg[$curr][$opt[0]] = $opt[1];
}
fclose($f);
?>
<html>
<body>
<!-- output the $cfg into form -->
<form action="save.php" method="POST">
<?php foreach ($cfg as $k => $v): ?>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $k; ?>" value="<?php echo $k; ?>" /><br/>
    <textarea name="<?php echo $k; ?>_v"><?php echo implode(',',$v); ?></textarea>
</p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the save.php:

```
<?php
# try to save the POST data into file
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `flaskcode` a web based code editor on python flask framework, which solves my case.

Allow others to modify config file without expose unnecessary part.

### How to

#### Installation

```
pip install flaskcode
```

#### Usage

```
flaskcode /path/to/resource/folder
```

By default, it will provide a code editor on "http://127.0.0.1:5001"

#### Reference

https://pypi.org/project/flaskcode/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30085044)